# Python 2.7.3 Math Flaw( 40 million is less then six hundred thousand )

Tags: math, python-2.7

**SOLVED**

In my program, it thinks that 40 million is less then 600,000.

Here is the code:
(Stop it after it loops 20 times)

```
import re
import urllib2
x = 0
d = 1
c = 1
highestmemberid = 1
highestmembercash = 4301848
while (d==1):
    x = float(x + 1)
    if (x==14 or x==3 or x==11 or x==13 or x==15):
        x = x + 1
    print x,
    url = "http://www.marapets.com/profile.php?id=" + str(x)
    home = opener.open(url)
    matchpoint = re.compile("<td align='left' valign=middle><B style='color:#(......);'>(.*?)</B></td>")
    home = home.read()
    home = home
    points = re.findall(matchpoint,home)
    if ("http://images.marapets.com/stuff/banned.gif" in home or  "This user does not exist" in home):
        print "banned/dosen't exist"
    else:
        mp = points[0][1]
        mp = mp.replace(" MP","")
        mpcheck= mp.replace(",","")
        mp = float(mpcheck)
        if (mpcheck > highestmembercash):
            highestmembercash = mpcheck
            highestmemberid = x
            print "richer"
        else:
            print "Not richer!"
        print mp
        print "The richest player in marapets is player id #: " + str(highestmemberid) + "Who has: " + str(highestmembercash) + " MP."
    if(x == 5368561):
        print "The richest player in marapets is player id #: " + str(highestmemberid) + "Who has: " + str(highestmembercash) + " MP."
```

What the program does is grab cash amounts from the page, and then sees if this is the highest amount. It loops about 5 million times.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: It is now as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpcheck` is a string, you want to check that `mp > highestmembercash` and assign `highestmembercash = mp`.

Comment: @Tyranitar: what are you talking about?  `mpcheck` is a string.  Then you set `mp = float(mpcheck)`.   Then you compare `mpcheck > highestmembercash`, not `mp`.

Comment: I deleted that comment.Before I thought anyone saw it. Your right DSM.